# Populate a word template using C# in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, ms-word

I read it some post referring to Populate word documents, but I need to populate a word document (Office 2007) using C#. For example i want to have a word document with a label [NAME], use that label in C# to put my value, and do all this in a ASP.NET MVC3 controller. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [OpenXML SDK](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5124) provided by Microsoft to manipulate Word documents. And here's a [nice article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469465%28v=office.12%29.aspx) (it's actually the third of a series of 3 articles) with a couple of examples.

Comment: Cool. I also find [this link](http://seroter.wordpress.com/2009/12/23/populating-word-2007-templates-through-open-xml/) very useful. But still dont get it work because of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9433332/open-xml-sdk-2-0) :(

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this :
- Introduce "signets" into your Word document template
- Work on a copy of your word template
- Modify signets values from c# code and save or print your file.

Be carefull with releasing correctly your word process if you treat several documents in your application :)

Answer (score 0):

OP's solution extracted from the question:

> The solution i found is this:
>
> ```
> static void Main(string[] args)
> {
>     Console.WriteLine("Starting up Word template updater ...");
>
>     //get path to template and instance output
>     string docTemplatePath = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Doc Offices XML\earth.docx";
>     string docOutputPath = @"C:\Users\user\Desktop\Doc Offices XML\earth_Instance.docx";
>
>     //create copy of template so that we don't overwrite it
>     File.Copy(docTemplatePath, docOutputPath);
>
>     Console.WriteLine("Created copy of template ...");
>
>     //stand up object that reads the Word doc package
>     using (WordprocessingDocument doc = WordprocessingDocument.Open(docOutputPath, true))
>     {
>         //create XML string matching custom XML part
>         string newXml = "<root>" +
>             "<Earth>Outer Space</Earth>" +
>             "</root>";
>
>         MainDocumentPart main = doc.MainDocumentPart;
>         main.DeleteParts<CustomXmlPart>(main.CustomXmlParts);
>
>         //MainDocumentPart mainPart = doc.AddMainDocumentPart();
>
>         //add and write new XML part
>         CustomXmlPart customXml = main.AddCustomXmlPart(CustomXmlPartType.CustomXml);
>         using (StreamWriter ts = new StreamWriter(customXml.GetStream()))
>         {
>
>             ts.Write(newXml);
>         }
>
>         //closing WordprocessingDocument automatically saves the document
>     }
>
>     Console.WriteLine("Done");
>     Console.ReadLine();
> }
> ```