# How can I pass values from View to a .doc template?

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, doc, generate

I have a view (edit.cshtml) that contains textboxes with values. 
I want user be able to click a button in the page, and the values passed to a .doc template, then user will be prompted where they want to save the .doc file (with the values already in the .doc). Are there any samples on these? I can't seem to find one.

Comment: This would be done in the controller.  There are plenty of MVC examples of sending data to the controller.

Comment: a little older but still seems relevant https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431018/populate-a-word-template-using-c-sharp-in-asp-net-mvc3